# How to implement 2 columns of stack view with subview evenly take horizontal space

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uikit

I want to implement something like in the image below: 2 columns of labels with random-length long strings that can take multiple lines, and the 2 columns of labels should take equal space horizontally
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have tried to implement it with 2 stackViews each left and right to contain the labels, and an outer stackView to make the 2 evenly take horizontal space, but it turns out to look like the below:(there is a blank space vertically on the right side)

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**Part of the code I used to implement this:**

```
private lazy var stackLeft: UIStackView = {
    let stackLeft = UIStackView()
    stackLeft.axis = .vertical
    stackLeft.alignment = .top
    return stackLeft
}()

private lazy var stackRight: UIStackView = {
    let stackRight = UIStackView()
    stackRight.axis = .vertical
    stackRight.alignment = .top
    return stackRight
}()

private lazy var outerStack: UIStackView = {
    let outerStack = UIStackView()
    outerStack.axis = .horizontal
    outerStack.distribution = .fillEqually
    return outerStack
}()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provably this should work:

```
private lazy var stackLeft: UIStackView = {
    let stackLeft = UIStackView()
    stackLeft.axis = .vertical
    return stackLeft
}()

private lazy var stackRight: UIStackView = {
    let stackRight = UIStackView()
    stackRight.axis = .vertical
    return stackRight
}()

private lazy var outerStack: UIStackView = {
    let outerStack = UIStackView()
    outerStack.axis = .horizontal
    outerStack.distribution = .fillEqually
    outerStack.alignment = .top
    return outerStack
}()
```